# How to install Android app on LG smart TV?

Tags: android, android-tv, lg, smart-tv

I have android app apk on my USB, I inserted it in my LG smart tv, it shows me USB device, but apk is not visible... Any ideas what's the issue with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great guide how to do that, if your TV is android TV: https://pedronveloso.com/how-to-install-an-apk-on-android-tv/

Have you enabled 'unknown sources' from security and restrictions settings?

Comment: @Petar, well if you noticed I have that if clause on my answer "...how to do that, IF your TV is android TV". So I am not making any comments about if this question has any conflicting facts in it. Answer was based on personal experience with Android TVs, since this question has "android-tv" label in it. The questioner marked this answer as a correct one, so at least his/her question was answered.

Comment: @Moyote - I removed my remark about wrong answer. Actually question is unclear. Is he dealing with android TV or he is trying to install APK "presuming" it's an android TV. I haven't seen LG android for years, so I am bit puzzled with his question. However, you answer is great but only if he's talking about Android. Cheers !

Answer (score 17):

LG, VIZIO, SAMSUNG and PANASONIC TVs are not android based, and you cannot run APKs off of them... You should just buy a fire stick and call it a day. The only TVs that are android-based, and you can install APKs are: SONY, PHILIPS and SHARP.
#FACTS.

Comment: You forgot PHILCO and TOSHIBA [Semp] ; they have some models running Android OS as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the research FIRESTICK is a solution for non Android based but there's another one Im using if you guys want to try it let me know...

LG, VIZIO, SAMSUNG and PANASONIC TVs are not android based, and you cannot run APKs off of them... You should just buy a fire stick and call it a day. The only TVs that are android-based, and you can install APKs are: SONY, PHILIPS and SHARP, PHILCO and TOSHIBA.